# How to access properties of referenced objects in Jinja2 templates (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Consider the following data model in Google App Engine

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    b = ndb.KeyProperty(Kind='B')

class B(ndb.Model):
    name = StringProperty()
```

now suppose that in a Python Http Request Handler I execute this query

```
entities = A.query().fetch(200)
```

and I pass entities as template value to a Jinja2 template

where I iterate over A objects like

```
{%for a in entities%}

  {{a.name}}

{% endfor %}
```

The question is: how can I access the properties of the B object referenced by A in the Jinja2 template? Something like {{a.b.name}}

Comment: `a.b.get().name` _might_ work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the key (b) to the entity, so you can get it directly:

```
{% set b_entity = a.b.get() %}
{{ b_entity.name }}
```

(Using the `set` in case you have other properties in the entity.  That way you only need to do the `get()` once)

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707972/google-app-engine-datastore-referenced-entitydeletion

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the [ndb asyc api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async) might be useful...

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_b_instances_from_a_instances(a_instance):
    b_instance = yield a_instance.b.get_async()
    raise ndb.Return((a_instance, b_instance))

entities = A.query().map(get_b_instances_from_a_instances, limit=200)
```

Now your `entities` [will be a list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_map) of 2-tuples where each has an instance of `A` and it's corresponding instance of `B`.